# How default ASP.NET MVC 3 project account controller work

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

**I am new in MVC3.** When i create a new default ASP.NET MVC 3 project template.

[image: My choosing MVC3 template]

There is a AccountModels.cs and AccountController.cs C# class that handle data from a ASPNETDB.MDF DB file, there is a connection string (XML) in Web.config file,  but i can't understand how it handle those data where is the Query or LINQ, **How AccountModels.cs or AccountController.cs file know those DB tables** Can anyone make me understand step by step? please someone help me please.

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is using Microsoft [Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx).

From the doc:

> ASP.NET membership gives you a built-in way to validate and store user
>   credentials. ASP.NET membership therefore helps you manage user
>   authentication in your Web sites. You can use ASP.NET membership with
>   ASP.NET forms authentication by using with the ASP.NET login controls
>   to create a complete system for authenticating users.

Basically it has quick straight forward configuration and creates a couple of tables in your database to keep user data.
It is flexible, but the interfaces are not very well segregated and if you need to extend it or plug your custom logic you may end up defining a tons of method throwing "Not Implemented" exception